# which database should i prefer for application with millions of data

Tags: asp.net, oracle, sql-server-2008

We are going to develope one web application using Asp.Net which can have millions of data to handle

so i am confuse between database selection

which should i prefer sql server or oracle with respect to performance and all criteria

please guide me on this

thanks

Comment: both are do great job. Its up to you to create a good designed database and make it fast.

Comment: yes right, but i mean which is best among these for long term and heavy transactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is looks subjective, how ever I like to answer and say that:

[If some one gives you to drive a formula one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGUZJVY-sHo), in how many seconds you gong to crash it? Probably you do not even manage to start it running.

The same think is on programming. Both programs are like formula one, maybe one have some feature and the other have some other, but they can run so fast if "you can drive them" like that.

Now it's up to you to make a good design to the database and make it real fast, or very slow and huge. It's not the machine, it you that you can make it run fast. It's not the formula one on the races, it’s the pilot (and the rest team) that they drive them so fast.